# Need explanation of this, what actually is going on in this line?

Tags: c++, vector

I am converting some C++ code into python. but I am not sure what exactly this line do.

```
vector<double>().swap(prev);
```

I compiled a simple program to see what it actually do, I found that it resizes the vector "prev" to 0.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
vector<int> ax;
ax.reserve(10);          
for(int i=99; i<110; ++i){
    ax.push_back(i);
}
for(int i=0; i<ax.size(); ++i){
  std::cout << ax[i] << ' ';

}

vector<int>().swap(ax);
cout<<"\nAfter space \n";
cout<<"size is "<<ax.size();

for(int i=0; i<ax.size(); ++i){
  std::cout << ax[i];

}
}
```

Comment: Yes it's poorly formatted, but the question is answerable and the answer (if I may say so myself) informative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the result of the programmer deciding that, for some reason,

```
vector<int>().swap(ax);
```

is clearer than

```
ax.clear();
```

(The former exchanges the initially empty anonymous temporary `vector<int>()` with `ax`).

---

Somewhat less cyncially perhaps, the `swap` method *might* reset the *capacity* of the vector, whereas `clear()` never does. But it's still an odd choice: if you want the capacity to be reset then use

```
ax.clear();
ax.shrink_to_fit();
```

but even *that* is not guaranteed to reset the capacity; it's up to the implementation to decide.

Comment: The "some reason" is probably that on some (most?) implementations the `swap` version also resets the capacity , whereas `clear` doesn't

Comment: Neither the "swap version" nor the `ax = std::vector<int>()` are guaranteed to reset capacity before C++17, since there was nothing to prevent the default constructor setting capacity to zero. From C++17 it is more likely that the default constructor leaves capacity as zero, since the constructor is `noexcept` which is tough to guarantee if the vector allocates a non-zero capacity. That's partly why C++11 introduced a `shrink_to_fit()` member function to request reducing capacity to the size. Painfully, though, it is implementation-defined whether `shrink_to_fit()` actually changes capacity.

Comment: @Peter: Very good points; I think my `ax = std::vector<int>()` was defective in all current standards; I've amended the answer a little - hopefully not to the offence of the upvoters.